# Доступ к файлам маппинга для пользователя хост машины

Tags: docker

Настраиваю окружение проекта в докере, первый раз с ним работаю, столкнулся с проблемой прав доступа к файлам созданным юзером докера.

```
mysql:
 image: mysql:8.0
 command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
 volumes:
  - ./storage/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
 environment:
  - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
  - "MYSQL_USER=app"
  - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
  - "MYSQL_DATABASE=app"
 ports:
  - "33061:3306"
 restart: always
```

Как видим маппинг есть

```
volumes:
  - ./storage/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Юзера хост машины добавил в группу docker, что позволило запускать команды не от sudo, но при запуске командой `docker-compose up --build -d` вылетает ошибка прав доступа `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` к каталогу `/storage/docker/mysql`, так как владелец этого каталога некий "999" и группа root. 
Если запустить от sudo то в таком случае все отлично запускается, ноя не знаю правильно ли так делать?
Так же если я запускаю от пользователя хост машины но без опции --build то запускается без проблем, видимо не вносятся никакие изменения в `/storage/docker/mysql`

В общем вопрос заключается в том как запускать от пользователя хост машины докер командой `docker-compose up --build -d` ?

Comment: Создайте именованный volume вместо маппинга папок.

Comment: @zalex можете привести пример ?

Comment: Да  там особо ни какого примера. Вот в документации что написано - 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/
А ежели мы говорим про docker-compose файл, то попросту вместо 
`- ./storage/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`  вы пишете что то типа - `mysqlVolume:/var/lib/mysql` и сможете наблюдать ваш том  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/

Именованый том в этом случае должен создаться автоматически, просто вы указываете не путь к локальной папке, а имя.